# Variable set by await is undefined after await expression evaluated

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have some code that's using async/await that is giving me a very odd problem: the variable that I set with an await statement is throwing an undefined reference rrror after the expression! Here's the code:

```
export const fetchPrices = async ({ commit }, ticker) => {
  const key= "*********";
  const url =
    `http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${ticker}&interval=1min&apikey=${key}`

  commit(FETCH_PRICES_REQUEST, { ticker })

  try {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let priceData = await response.json();
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  commit(FETCH_PRICES_SUCCESS, priceData)
};
```

When this runs, the last line of the function throws a couple of errors:

> ReferenceError: response is not defined

and

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: priceData is not defined

This does not make a whole lot of sense to me as my understanding is that the whole usage of await is that the assignment to the variable should have been completed by the next line of code.

I actually worked out the fix for this, which had to do with where I'd declared the variables. When I moved the declaration outside of the try/catch block by placing the following line at the top of the function, it worked:

```
let response, priceData;
```

Getting curious, I looked at the transformed code in Babel. With the declaration at the top of the file, it looks like this:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

var fetchPrices = exports.fetchPrices = function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(_ref2, ticker) {
    var commit = _ref2.commit;
    var response, priceData, key, url;
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            response = void 0, priceData = void 0;
            key = "EH6GPZQ5X8EUM3MC";
            url = "http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=" + ticker + "&interval=1min&apikey=" + key;


            commit(FETCH_PRICES_REQUEST, { ticker: ticker });

            _context.prev = 4;
            _context.next = 7;
            return fetch(url);

          case 7:
            response = _context.sent;
            _context.next = 10;
            return response.json();

          case 10:
            priceData = _context.sent;
            _context.next = 16;
            break;

          case 13:
            _context.prev = 13;
            _context.t0 = _context["catch"](4);

            console.error(_context.t0);

          case 16:

            commit(FETCH_PRICES_SUCCESS, priceData);

          case 17:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee, undefined, [[4, 13]]);
  }));

  return function fetchPrices(_x, _x2) {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();
```

The key difference is the line at the top of the first case (`case 0`):

```
response = void 0, priceData = void 0;
```

What seems to happen is if you don't declare the variables at the top of the function, then cases 7 and 10 fail when they try to assign to those variables.

My question is whether or not this is a problem with the async/await compiled code or whether my attempt to declare the variables inside the try/catch block was fundamentally wrong.

Comment: `let` is block scoped. When you declare these variables in `try{}` they are scoped to that block created by the braces.

Comment: variabled defined with let/const are blocked scope

Comment: @MarkMeyer but response is accessed in the same block no?

Comment: You must be using the name `response` somewhere else. You also said you are getting a reference area for `data` but I don't see `data`. I do see `priceData` defined in the `try` block and used outside the block.

Comment: @Akrion `response` is, but then outside of the try/catch, the op attempts to use `priceData`, which is still scoped to the `try`. This scenario is a perfect example of adding these requests to an array and using `promise.all` to resolve and run the ` commit(FETCH_PRICES_SUCCESS, priceData)` function, imo.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, I changed the variable names a few times and forgot to update the comment I put into the question. I will update now.

Comment: @sesamechicken haha I completely missed the `commit(FETCH_PRICES_SUCCESS, priceData)`! Thanks!

Comment: @sesamechicken does it make sense to add an answer explaining the scenario you described? Although, I suppose the answer is just that let is block scoped.

Comment: @fraxture, the issue _really_ is a scope problem, but `promise.all` will alleviate pain when you may have multiple successive awaits.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

The solution here -- as indicated by @Mark Meyer and @sesamechicken -- was a scoping error. Let is block-scoped, and so `priceData` was undefined outside of the try {} block. The solution was to defined these variables outside of the try block. Using a `var` would also probably work.